# Char[] array help needed

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string

I have a collection of objects from a database that holds the titles of companies.

I need to get the first letters (char[]) of all the titles distincted (.Distinct()).

Currently I have something like:

```
public char[] GetBrandsAlphabet()
    {
        using (var dc = ReturnContext())
        {
            var resultBrands =
                from brands in dc.Brands
                orderby brands.Title ascending
                select brands.Title.ToCharArray()[0];

            char[] ret = new char[resultBrands.Distinct().Count()];



        }
    }
```

Comment: Anything wrong (besides your code not returning anything)?

Comment: Rather than say how much you need help ("massively"), try telling us what your problem is. The question title is supposed to describe the question. As a general rule of thumb, none of us care *how much* you need help. But those who are able to help will do so if you describe the problem and we are able to solve it.

Comment: This seems almost like a homework assignment.

Comment: Sorry! The "Massive" is an "Array" in russian!!! So my question remake looks like Char[] array help needed. ))) Sorry!

Comment: ha! I just went to google tranlate to verify that, they sound almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return resultBrands.Distinct().ToArray();
```

However, this might not work exactly the way that you want, since `Distinct` could, in principle, change the ordering of the elements. I would remove the `orderby` statement from the sql statement and use:

```
return resultBrands.Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the last line with this:

```
char[] ret = resultBrands.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Or, hey, how about this one liner to replace everything else?

```
char[] ret = (from brands in dc.Brands 
              select brands.Title.ToUpper[0]).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();
```

The `ToUpper` guarantees that you won't have both 'A' and 'a' in your final array.

Answer (score 1):

OK What others already said. You can improve this part though:

```
  var resultBrands =
                from brands in dc.Brands
                orderby brands.Title ascending
                select brands.Title[0];
```

A string is already addressable by index like a char array, you don't need to convert it.